# Counting lastest dup values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I would like count the most recent similar values in a table like this

[image]

So the most recent status value is A, and there are 2 CONTINUOUSLY "A" values.

How to make a query that count the MOST RECENT, CONTINUOUS values? In this case I need a query that returns 2 at the end of the day

Thank you

Comment: How do you determine the order? There's no date column.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? With 8.0 you can use window functions like `LAG()`